# Header Menu and Sidebar Menu break when I insert an HTML Snippet

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have a post in my WordPress site. Here I am adding this code snippet:

```
<pre><code class="iframe-fragment"></code></pre>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.iframe-fragment').load('https://roboticsys.com/support/plugins/servlet/docs/c1001-d1003/RapidCode/_absolute_motion_8cs-example.html div.fragment', function(res, status, xhr){
    $("a.code").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);       
      var _href = $this.attr("href"); 
      $this.attr("href", 'https://roboticsys.com/support/plugins/servlet/docs/c1001-d1003/RapidCode/' + _href);
    });
 });
</script>
```

When I add this snippet of code to my post you can see it perfectly working and showing what it is supposed to. However, the main menu stops acting like it does on the homepage, and the sidebar menu cannot longer expand.

Here is the post I am working on: https://roboticsys.com/absolute-motion/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.change the jQuery library to latest one (or newer one) to support `$` like below:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2.Wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){..});` like below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.iframe-fragment').load('https://roboticsys.com/support/plugins/servlet/docs/c1001-d1003/RapidCode/_absolute_motion_8cs-example.html div.fragment', function(res, status, xhr){
        $("a.code").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);       
            var _href = $this.attr("href"); 
            $this.attr("href", 'https://roboticsys.com/support/plugins/servlet/docs/c1001-d1003/RapidCode/' + _href);
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Note:- try to check browser console that you have any other error related to jQuery (like conflict because of two different jQuery library used etc...) and try to rectify them

Comment: i changed: <script src=".../jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js">  to <script src=".../jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> and the sidebar worked. But the header is still not working properly. I also wrapped my code like you suggested.

Comment: @JPGarza  i have added that too, sorry i skip that. But still i will recommend the 2nd part also.